# Excel formating to multiples of decimals

Tags: excel

I would like to display a value of a cell to the nearest multiple of a fraction, say 1/8th, but to preserve the actual value of the cell, ie. avoiding using the ROUND function.  For example;

`0.44` in [A1] would display as `0.5`,

`0.33` in [A2] would display as `0.375`, and

`=A1+A2` in [A3] would display as `0.75` (rather than `0.875`)

Is it possible to format in such a manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no formatting that can round to intervals other than decimals.

What I would do is keep your raw values in one hidden cell, then round it in another cell that references the raw value, and show that cell.

Alternatively, you can [display numbers as fractions](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/display-numbers-as-fractions-0121ecac-1773-4f2d-8cd3-7db51fd83b77) , but it doesn't simplify fractions (e.g. it will display 0.5 as 4/8)

Comment: Although for the specific case of eighths, you can choose fraction format.

Comment: @TomSharpe I forgot about that. Added. Thanks!